# The elegant way to resolve negative zero in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, zero

I have to multiply the sign of all elements in an array.

For example 1:

```
input: [1, 2, 3]
output: 1
Explain: 1 * 1 * 1 = 1
```

Ex2:

```
input: [1, -2, 3]
output: -1
Explain: 1 * (-1) * 1 = -1
```

Ex3:

```
input: [1, -2, 3, 0]
output: 0
Explain: 1 * (-1) * 1 * 0 = 0
```

And here is my solution

```
function cal(A)
{
    return A.reduce((total, currentValue) => total * Math.sign(currentValue), 1);
}
```

However, the output of ex3 `cal([1, -2, 3, 0])` is `-0`.

I've already thought about adding one more condition like this

```
function cal(A)
{
    var total = A.reduce((total, currentValue) => total * Math.sign(currentValue), 1);
    if(total === 0)
        return 0;
    else
        return total;
}
```

And obviously, It looks ugly. Is there a more elegant way to resolve that?

Comment: `-0 || 0` returns `0`.

Comment: Indeed. just a matter of `total * Math.sign(currentValue) || 0`

Comment: Same trick as the comment above mine. `-0` is *falsy*, so the short-circuit OR evaluates to `0`.

Comment: @NguyễnVănPhong - What result do you want for `[1, -0, 1]`? That will factor into what you do with the `Math.sign` results for `0` and `-0`.

Comment: Hi, @T.J.Crowder. The output I'm expecting is just `-1 or 0 or 1` only. Anyway, that's a good point.

Comment: By your examples you want to return `1` when there is a `0` but if there's a 0 no need to reduce the rest, so an initial check for 0 seems straight forward.

Comment: Hi, @T.J.Crowder. Input doesn't have `-0`. But in your case, output stills expect `0` due to `-0 == 0` in my case.

Comment: Then you need to edit `Ex.3` to indicate that the output should be `0`

Comment: Oh, I see. Let me edit it right now. Thanks for your pointing out. It's my typo. @pilchard

Comment: What's so bad testing against 0? If you use a for loop you can immediately return 0 and dont have to process the rest of the elements.

Comment: I would just use a `for...of` and return early if `n === 0`, `reduce()` locks you in to iterating the complete array even after a `0` is encountered.

Comment: I've already thought about that solution. But in my case, I don't want to use `if else`. Furthermore, I'm curious about `-0 vs 0` in JS.

Comment: It's not just JS, see: [Signed zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero)

Comment: Then just add 0. `return A.reduce((total, currentValue) => total * Math.sign(currentValue), 1) + 0;`

Comment: Oh yeah, that looks quite pretty. Thanks @pilchard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to avoid conditional checks and keep the function purely computational you can use the curious rules of `-0` to simply add 0 to the result of your `reduce()` which will have no effect on non-zero results but will have the effect of converting `-0` to `0`.

```js
function cal(arr) {
  return arr.reduce((a, c) => a * Math.sign(c), 1) + 0;
}

console.log(cal([1, 2, 3]));     // 1
console.log(cal([1, -2, 3]));    // -1
console.log(cal([1, -2, 3, 0])); // 0
```

See [signed zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero) for more general discussion.

Comment: It is not necessary to add the + 0 at the end. The code return arr.reduce((a, c) => a * Math.sign(c), 1); works well

Comment: @DavideLorenzoMARINO Did you read the question? The OP is trying to avoid returning `-0`

Comment: Yes and also tried your code removing the + 0. It works. In the case of [1, -2, 3, 0] Your code will generate the result as ((((1 * 1) * -1) * 1) * 0) + 0  where I used the parenthesis to show the real sequence of operations. Why do you think that removing the + 0 at the end will give a different result?

Comment: Because `-0 + 0 = 0`

Comment: -0 is 0. 0 has no sign. And console.log(-0) prints 0. So adding + 0 is a non sense

Comment: That is categorically incorrect. While `0 === -0` evaluates to true, `1/0 !== 1/-0` (`+∞ !== -∞`)

Answer (score 2):

In your example, there is no need to multiply all the values. If there is at least one zero, the result is zero, so there is no need to iterate through the entire array. Example below:

```js
function compute(arr)
{
    let result = true;
    for (let item of arr) {
        if (item === 0) return 0;
        if (item < 0) result = !result;
    }
    return result ? 1 : -1;
}

console.log(compute([1, 2, 3]));
console.log(compute([1, -2, 3]));
console.log(compute([1, -2, 3, 0]));
```

Answer (score 1):

My code Checks whether , if the array contains a 0, the result will always be 0, regardless of the signs of the other elements. For all other cases, it will calculate the product of the signs as before.

```js
function cal(A) {
  return A.reduce((total, currentValue) => {
    if (currentValue === 0) {
      return 0; // if 0 in array return 0
    }
    return total * Math.sign(currentValue);
  }, 1);
}
console.log(cal([1, 2, 3]))       // 1
console.log(cal([1, -2, 3]));     //-1
console.log(cal([1, -2, 3, 0]));  // 0
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```